# How do you sepearte paired values in a python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list=[(1,10),(4,5),(2,7)]
How to i separate the three paired elements into 6 unpaired ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
# List of tuple initialization
lt = [(1,10), (4,5), (2,7)]
  
# get each element of each tuple
out = [item for t in lt for item in t]
  
# printing output
print(out)
```

The output is then:

> [1, 10, 4, 5, 2, 7]

Source: this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-list-of-tuples-into-list/) and documentation linked above.